# App startup routing in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm writing an application in Backbone and am exploring ways of rendering at startup. My app is largely data driven and depends on several API calls before the landing page can be drawn.

My app structure contains a main view containing several subviews which contain the majority of data. Navigation is controlled in the router. I'm using require.js to handle module loading.

The problem I'm facing is I'm not sure how to go about having the router defer rendering a view until data is loaded, or even where this logic should live. I've tried adding my main app view into the router via require, but it hasn't yet instantiated at runtime (it logs as `function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }` instead of the view).

What patterns are used to handle deferred rendering of views? Is it appropriate to put methods in my collections to trigger drawing on the initial load, or are there better ways to consolidate logic?

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion, for usability you must 'tell' the user that something is happening in you application.

As you said, you have a lot of data to load on the main view, so you coul try to show some loading information to user, when you're requesting data.

To implement this, you can intercept all the requisition that you model or collection does, and when it starts you just show you loading content, and when you request finish you remove the loading content.

Something like this ( Coffeescript Code).

```
define [
    'jquery'
], ($) ->
   loadElement = $('someContent')

 $(document)
```

.ajaxStart(-> $(loadElement).show())

.ajaxStop(-> $(loadElement).hide())

Or you can just wait for the request finish and render the content.

Both ways you'll need to listen for the model events inside your views and react when something return from server.

If you'd like i could send you some example code of how to do that.

Take Care

Comment: My question is purely architectural. Although a progress indicator is important for the user experience, I'm only asking about application design as it relates to using routes in an application.